# An alternative to @Value annotation in static function

Tags: java, spring, static, annotations

It's not possible to use `@Value` on a static variable.

```
@Value("${some.value}")
static private int someValue;

static public void useValue() {
    System.out.println(someValue);
}
```

When I do this, `0` is printed. So what is a good alternative to this?

Comment: If you ask for an alternative: what is the context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring inject noting in static field (by default).

So you have two alternatives:

- (the better one) make the field non static
- (the ugly hack) add an none static setter which writes in the static field, and add the `@Value` annotation to the setter.

---

- and then there is the [trick with the MethodInvokingFactoryBean](http://planproof-fool.blogspot.com/2010/03/spring-setting-static-fields.html) -- this example is for autowired fiels, but I guess you can adapt it for `@Value` too

Comment: Can I access to properties value from static function in non-spring way?

Comment: @Sangdol: via the application context: http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/03/accessing-spring-beans-from-legacy-code.html

Answer (score 7):

Use this simple trick to achieve what you want (way better than having the value injected into non-static setters and writing so a static field - as suggested in the accepted answer):

```
@Service
public class ConfigUtil {
    public static ConfigUtil INSTANCE;

    @Value("${some.value})
    private String value;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        INSTANCE = this;        
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Use like:

`ConfigUtil.INSTANCE.getValue();`

Comment: Upvoted for food solution to OP's question (given that static context is required). However I would not call this a 'trick' but mention the pattern's name: Singleton: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: `NullPointException` is thrown because `INSTANCE` is null when I test this code. I'm suspecting `ConfigUtil` needs to be injected itself for `@PostConstruct` to work (which kinds of defeat the purpose of using static methods)

Comment: @jack3694078  I also got NullPointException

Answer (score 0):

To **prevent ever repeating injections of the same value making a field non-static** in a class that gets instantiated very often, I preferred to create a simple Singleton ConfigUtil as a workaround:

```
package de.agitos.app.util;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

/**
 * Helper class to get injected configuration values from static methods
 * 
 * @author Florian Sager
 *
 */

@Configurable
public class ConfigUtil {

    private static ConfigUtil instance = new ConfigUtil();

    public static ConfigUtil getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private @Value("${my.value1}") Integer value1;

    public Integer getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }
}
```

Inside the class I tried to inject the value first as a static Integer:

```
private static Integer value1 = ConfigUtil.getInstance().getValue1();
```

Comment: I tried  this and it does not work (of course, because you construct the `ConfigUtil` using the `new` operator.

Comment: True, it does not work even if it's annotated with @configurable.

Answer (score 0):

The following codes work for me,

```
public class MappingUtils {

  private static String productTypeList;

  @Value("${productType-list}")
  public void setProductTypeList(String productTypeList) {
    MappingUtils.getProductTypeList = productTypeList;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have a class name called config
so you initialize the static variable.
May be one can use the below approach for the same

```
class Config
{
 
 private static int someValue;
 
 private Config(@Value("${some.value}") int valueDuringInitialization)//private constructor
 {
    Config.someValue=valueDuringInitialization;
 }
 
 static public void useValue() {
    System.out.println(someValue);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but you have to annotate the class as a Service, Controller, or something.

```
@Value("${name}")
private String name;

private static String NAME_STATIC;

@Value("${name}")
public void setNameStatic(String name){
    PropertyController.NAME_STATIC = name;
}
```