# Spring - inject value for request header name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

There is a problem with Spring and injecting request header name value into controller.
Here is the code:

```
@Controller
public class ApiController {

    @Value("${param.header_name}")
    private String param;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/**")
    public void handleApiRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestHeader(value = param) final String param)
```

Properties are defined using **`@PropertySource`** and **`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`**.

The problem is:

> "The value for annotation attribute RequestHeader.value must be a
>   constant expression."

But it is not possible to inject a value to a constant (final static) field. Is there a workaround for this? I would like to use `RequestHeader` annotation / mapping and property file to define the header name.

Comment: No, you cannot assign a dynamic value to a Spring bean's member variable - Why would you want this to happen?

If you need this header variable in your `handleApiRequest()` method, you can retrieve it there from the `request` using `request.getHeader(header_name)`. Why would you want to use it in your `@Value` property?

Comment: Hi @Fazovsky, Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897201/an-alternative-to-value-annotation-in-static-function

Comment: @Alexander I think RequestHeader annotation is cleaner then request.getHeader(...)

Comment: this is very strange ... you can use property placeholder configuration in `@RequestMapping` annotation but you can't in `@RequestHeader`...sounds like missing implementation or i don't know.
`@RequestMapping(value = "/${spring-content-type}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<String> params(@RequestHeader(value = "${spring-content-type}",required = false) String contentType){
        System.out.println("content type is "+contentType);
        return Stream.of("1","2").collect(toList());
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Values used in annotations must be resolvable at compile-time, but `param`'s value can only be determined at runtime

The only solution I see is to use [`HttpServletRequest.getHeader(String)`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader(java.lang.String)):

```java
String headerValue = request.getHeader(param);
```

Comment: OK. I think that's the only way.

Comment: @Fazovsky Well, if you want to play, you may try to override `RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(...)` method `;)`

Comment: How can `@RequestMapping` accept a property placeholder then? Is it because the placeholder is just a regular string at that point?

Comment: @GerardoCauich Yes exactly. [Annotations only accept compile-time constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1) (plus [class literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) and [enum constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1)), which [aren't simple `final static` fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).