# Java 11 + maven + lombok + spring boot project returning Can't extract module name from xpp3_min-1.1.4c

Tags: maven, spring-boot, lombok, java-11, java-platform-module-system

I have a very simple project based on Spring Boot, Java 11 and Lombok. I can't build it (see error bellow). I read here https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1723 some people complaining about Java 11 modularity with Lombok but since the issue is almost one year ago and the description is different than mine I will assume it is not relevant for my case.

It seams that I am missing some concept either regard during compiling (eg. some extra step in pom.xml) or somehow adding Lombok in module-path.

```
package com.test.common;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class CommonApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CommonApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

...

```
package com.test.common.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@ToString
public class JwtConfig {

    // Spring doesn't inject/autowire to "static" fields. 
    // Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6897406
    @Value("${security.jwt.uri:/auth/**}")
    private String Uri;

    @Value("${security.jwt.header:Authorization}")
    private String header;

    @Value("${security.jwt.prefix:Bearer }")
    private String prefix;

    @Value("${security.jwt.expiration:#{24*60*60}}")
    private int expiration;

    @Value("${security.jwt.secret:JwtSecretKey}")
    private String secret;
```

...

```
module common {
    exports com.test.common.security;
    exports com.test.common;


    requires lombok;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.cloud.netflix.eureka.client;
}
```

...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>common</name>
    <description>Zuul project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Complete error:

```
PS C:\_d\WSs\soteste\common> mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.test:common >---------------------------
[INFO] Building common 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ common ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ common ---
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar: Provider class org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer not in module
[WARNING] ********************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING] * Required filename-based automodules detected. Please don't publish this project to a public artifact repository! *
[WARNING] ********************************************************************************************************************
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\_d\WSs\soteste\common\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ common ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\_d\WSs\soteste\common\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ common ---
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar: Provider class org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer not in module
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\_d\WSs\soteste\common\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ common ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. See FAQ web page and the dump file C:\_d\WSs\soteste\common\target\surefire-reports\2019-03-20T18-47-40_749-jvmRun1.dumpstream
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.032 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-20T18:47:42-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project common: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\_d\WSs\soteste\common\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java" @C:\Users\resource\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire12554810325212725181\surefireargs18082250267355398068 C:\Users\resource\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire12554810325212725181 2019-03-20T18-47-40_749-jvmRun1 surefire11396085758725333238tmp surefire_06534283884049913949tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java" @C:\Users\resource\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire12554810325212725181\surefireargs18082250267355398068 C:\Users\resource\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire12554810325212725181 2019-03-20T18-47-40_749-jvmRun1 surefire11396085758725333238tmp surefire_06534283884049913949tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:669)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: For a Spring Boot Project I would ask: Why do you like to use Java modules?

Comment: khmarbaise, I guess got your point. I believe you are saying two things in fact: 1 - since Spring relies on reflection and Modularity isn't compliance with reflection I will not be able to take real advantage of Spring stack. 2 - since the greatst advavntage of Spring Boot is easy setup for several frameworks I will not take real advantage trying to decrease the jar package. Assuming it is the reason  you asked me "why", I believe I must keep using Spring Boot reling on classpath and completely ignore modules, right?

Comment: Yes Spring Boot relies on reflection which violates the Java Module System. Yes the easy setup etc. What do you mean by: `..trying to decrease the jar package..` Do you mean the size?

Comment: khmarbaise, I was interested to take advantage of Jigsaw (eg. create smaller jar with embbeded JRE and more control over packages visibility).

Comment: khmarbaise, if you answer that my error was tryng to mix Spring Boot with modularity I will point as answer to my question. Basically, after I removed the modularity feature (I mean I deleted module-info.java for both projects and, since both are Spring Boot projects, I added in the dependency project <plugin>...<classifier>exec</classifier>.. This fix my issue at all

Comment: Ok. So next step could be to try to get spring-boot-app into a runtime image via jlink ..but I'm not sure if you will succeed.

Comment: Which Maven version are you using?

Comment: # mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T15:41:47-03:00)
Maven home: C:\_d\tools\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
Default locale: pt_BR, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"